# How do I resolve conflicting assertion types in Angular?

Tags: angular, jasmine, cypress, assertion

I am developing an Angular application that uses the Jasmine framework for regular unit testing and the Cypress framework for end-to-end testing.

While I have had no trouble conducting my E2E tests with Cypress, the `spec.` files used with Jasmine inside my source code folder `src` all underline the `toBe` method calls in red and display the following error message:

`TS2339: Property 'toBe' does not exist on type 'Assertion'`

A code sample for one my tests is displayed below:

```
it('Should have a category of \'A\'', () => {(
    expect(category.category).toBe('A');
})
```

After doing research, I have discovered that the problem is due to both frameworks using the same assertion library. I have tried applying solutions from the following two posts but neither have worked.

- [Cypress causing type errors in jest assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58999086/cypress-causing-type-errors-in-jest-assertions)
- [How do I resolve conflicting type identifiers for Cypress and jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69291905/how-do-i-resolve-conflicting-type-identifiers-for-cypress-and-jquery)

Both solutions suggest editing one or more of the `tsconfigjson` files, though since I have started to use Cypress at version 10 and above, the `cypress` root folder has not come with its own config file.

Comment: What angular version are you on?

Comment: I am on version 13.3.12

Comment: `tsconfig.json` is something independent of Cypress - it is a configuration file for TypeScript, and Cypress does not create one when it does it's initial setup. You can easily make your own in `cypress/` and follow the instructions in the answer for the second post to set up exclusions that avoid your issue.

Comment: I followed the solution for the second post and it seems to have worked. Thank you!